# LWC - Add Select List as filter

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on replacing an Aura component with a LWC. On my Aura I had select fields that were used as filters.  I had a function that was called from each filter field that filtered down the attribute used to display the data.  Here is an example of one of the filter fields:

```
 <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
        <!-- Create a dropdown menu with options for Section code-->
        <lightning:select aura:id="selectGroupNum" label="GroupNum" name="sourceGroupNum" onchange=" 
         {!c.FilterChanged}">
             <aura:iteration items="{!v.groupnumbers}" var="gs">
                 <option value="{!gs}" text="{!gs}" />
             </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
     </lightning:layoutItem>
```

How would I achieve the same thing using LWC?  First, what is the LWC equivalent to a lighting:select?  Second, since I'm not defining an attribute on the component, do I just create a separate list variable and in my function update that?  Thank you!!!!

Fred

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard LWC that's closest to `lightning:select` would be `lightning-combobox` ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example)). You should be able to translate this implementation entirely to the combobox component as it supports an `onchange` event that would work like the Aura component you've shared.

Replacing the `v.groupnumbers` attribute will likely be a property in your LWC class:

```html
<template>
    <!-- ... -->

    <lightning-combobox
        name="group-number-filter"
        label="My Filter" 
        options={groupNumbers}
        placeholder="Select an option"
        onchange={handleFilterChange}></lightning-combobox>

    <!-- ... -->

</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api groupNumbers = [];

    handleFilterChange(event) {
        // handle change, modify groupNumbers
    }

}
```